# Express.io and Android

Tags: android, node.js, express.io

I have been working in a chat app using nodejs and socket.io. I already have an Android client that works perfect in this schema. I started to use express.io instead of use express an socket.io separately. Everything works well except for my Android client. Im using https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-client-java socket client in Android, but my app never connect to my socket server.

I received the following error:
io.socket.engineio.client.EngineIOException: server error

Does anybody knows something about this issue?

Server side config:

```
    var express = require('express.io');
    var path = require('path');
    var logger = require('morgan');
    var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
    var multer  = require('multer');

    var app = express();

    app.http().io()


    app.io.route('storeClientInfo', function(req) {

        req.io.join(req.io.request.data.customId);

    });

    app.io.route('enviar_room', function(req) {

      app.io.room(req.params.correo).broadcast('new visitor');

    });

    // Start the server

    app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);

      var server = app.listen(app.get('port'), function() {
       console.log('Express server listening on port ' +                                     server.address().port);
      });
```

Android side:

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    try {

        mSocket = IO.socket(LoginActivity.URL_HOST);
        mSocket.on(Socket.EVENT_CONNECT_ERROR, onConnectError);
        mSocket.on("new visitor",onNuevoMensaje);
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
      ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    }

    private Emitter.Listener onConnectError = new Emitter.Listener() {
    @Override
    public void call(Object... args) {

        Log.d("SocketMsg: ", args[0].toString());

        for (Object o : args) {
            Log.i("IO " + Socket.EVENT_CONNECT_ERROR, o.toString());
        }

        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "CONNECT ERROR", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


            }
        });
    }
};
```

Currently I already have a Angularjs web version running with my server. The problem is that in Android i always received Socket.EVENT_CONNECT_ERROR.

Comment: Sounds like a networking issue. Can you upload your Android code as well as more of the error from the logcat?

Comment: could you try make sure that the server is accessible using socket.io at least browse for http://HOST:PORT/socket.io/socket.io.js if it is now working fine means its setup is not working fine, plz share how you are setup you server side code

Comment: HOST:PORT/socket.io/socket.io.js  is working, im using this on my Angular web app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After two days of tests I found that the problem was that Express.io include a socket.io version 0.9.6. The socket.io-client-java library (https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-client-java) support socket.io 1.x or later. I manually changed the socket.io version on Express.io to the 1.3.7 version. I just had to modify some parts of the code on the Express library.